# Load view after XHR request data blinded completely by resolver Angular 6

Tags: angular, binding, xmlhttprequest, url-routing, angular-universal

I'm using Angular Universal V6. I have a route "show-posts" and it has a huge XHR request on loading. When I open the `view source` version of this route, I see everithing rendered successfully but the place that should bind by XHR request data, is empty in source.

I'm, using a resolver :

```
{ path: 'show-posts/:post_id', 
  component: ShowPostComponent ,
  resolve  : {postData : getPostDataResolver}
}
```

And in ngOnInit:

```
this.route.data.subscribe( data =>{
  this.postData = data;
})
```

It seems a standard method for binding XHR data in Angular Universal for making SEO friendly pages. But it's not working. It show data to view but in "view source" version the scope is empty.

How can I fix it? It's working fine in all routes but in this route that Has huge XHR, does not work find.

Answer (score 0):

Yes using resolver is a good practice.  You told your router to resolve value named postData. So the first mistake I see is that in you Component don't read this resolved value. Your code should look like

```
this.route.data.subscribe(() => {
  this.postData = this.route.snapshot.data.postData;
});
```